# Why isnt the observers getting even though Get and WIll have been defined?

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

[image]

I have a class that has a willSet and didSet defined. I instantiated an object. I was expecting the two observers to be called, but that is not the case. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: It works for me. Both willSet and didSet were called. It may be a playground issue in your case.

Comment: Have you opened the output console on the right? You're not seeing the printouts on the right, because something else is already displayed there.